# Custrom 404 error, routing error stops the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In ApplicationController I added:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

# This code never reached when routing error occurs
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
end
```

As I am trying to catch  exceptions for not found pages, I've noticed that when routing error triggered, the code above never reached, as a result, `render_404` never called

`Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local` is false, Any idea ?

Here is what I get:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/not_there_route"):
  actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/deflater.rb:13:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: How is your `render_404` implemented? Is it possible your implementation attempts to render the original path again?

Comment: its implemented in application controller, but its not called because rescue_from is not executed above

Comment: Try running in staging / production mode, i dont think it will get to your exception handlers in development

Comment: I tried to test it at production mode,deployed to heroku, but no luck ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add catch all route, something like this:

```
match "*path", :to => "application#routing_error"
```

More detailed here http://www.bdunagan.com/2012/04/27/rescue_from-routingerror-in-rails-3/